# Makefile: what is "@-"?

Tags: makefile

In a makefile I use there is `@-`, that is not mentioned in any makefile tutorial I could find.. Could you please explain what `@-` is for?
For example:

```
@- $(RM) *.o
```

Comment: `@` dont echo command, `-` continue even if fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The at-sign `@` tells Make to not print the command line before executing it.
(Manual: [Recipe echoing](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html))

The minus sign `-` tells Make to ignore the result of the command and not fail the target if it was unsuccessful.
(Manual: [Errors in recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html))

In your case it's just both of them being used, because somebody did not want to pollute the output with the erase command, and did not want to fail the build if anything goes wrong with the deletion either.